# Ubuntu 20.10 Unattended install anyone?

Tags: preseed

Ubuntu has now discontinued the Debian installer support. Now what? I can't find any meaningful documentation for cloud-config (what is supposed to be used instead of preseed). There is no tool to generate this config file, besides a limited convert utility on git-hub, or examples.

Furthermore; when building VM's all the other suspects support directing virt-install to a URL containing the kernel to boot with using the --location command. --not Ubuntu anymore it seems? You have to use an ISO file... witch means that you cannot inject the unattended control file anymore. So now we are supposed to download and mess with ISO files? This cannot be the case.

May someone please provide the link to the Ubuntu step by step guide on how to automate installs for VM's and bare metal? NOT the cloud immutable images though... if I want to deploy Ubuntu in Azure or AWS I will simply use the pre-configured images there. The same function below works for multiple distros... except Ubuntu now...

Current function to install a new VM:

```bsh
    count=1
    for i in qemu-utils qemu-tools qemu-kvm qemu-system-x86 virt-install
    do
        write_status "${count}  - Verifying dependencies ( ${i} )..."
        check_dependencies $i &>/dev/null
        count=$((count + 1))
    done

    # Lookup specific binaries: use full path since they may just have been added and not in $PATH yet.
    : "${BIN_VIRT_INSTALL:=$(type -p virt-install)}"

    # Discover if the appropriate VM net interface is (default or br'0 - n')
    VIRT_NET="$(if ls /sys/class/net |grep br |grep -v virbr >/dev/null; then echo "bridge:$(ls /sys/class/net)" |grep br ; else echo default;fi)"

    # create image and run installer
    "${BIN_VIRT_INSTALL}" --name VDI_Ubuntu_"$CONFIG"_"$RANDOM" \
        --vcpus "${2:-2}" \
        --memory "${3:-2048}" \
        --network "${VIRT_NET}" \
        --disk size="${4:-30}" \
        --os-variant="${1:-debian10}" \
        --location=${SOURCE:-"http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/"} \
        --initrd-inject="$PRESEED_FILE" \
        --extra-args "ks=file:/$(basename $PRESEED_FILE)" \
        --noautoconsole || read -p "An ERROR has occurred. Please press [ENTER] to continue..."
```

Comment: One way, from the Ubuntu 20.04 Server Guide: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart

Comment: Still uses an ISO file that you have to download... I would rather just use the files that I need.